# inner join select on non-key column with where clause

Tags: mysql, join

i have the following query which provides me a list of entries always using the lastest entry as reference. (MAX(id)) .. however max(id) is not always the neewest entry ..

so is it somehow possible to get the id of the entry with the newest date (table has a unixtime date field)

current query

```
SELECT tr.id,user.ispro as ispro, user.id as user_id,tr.balance_e, user.paypal FROM tr
RIGHT join user on tr.user_id=user.id
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) as maxid FROM tr where tr.status='ok'
GROUP BY tr.user_id order by tr.date desc) la 
ON la.maxid = tr.id
WHERE tr.status='ok' and tr.balance_e >= ".$mincredit." 
ORDER BY tr.balance_e desc;
```

every time a entry is beeing updated (date) the output is incorrect since the INNER JOIN uses MAX(id) ... any idea how to change that to always have the id of the entry where the date field is the newest one ?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but it appears that the RIGHT JOIN could be replaced with an INNER JOIN with no change to functionality, but possible performance advantages.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT 
  tr.id, 
  user.ispro as ispro, 
  user.id as user_id,
  tr.balance_e,
  user.paypal 
FROM tr
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT user_id, MAX(date) as maxdate
   FROM tr 
   where tr.status='ok'
   GROUP BY tr.user_id
) la ON tr.user_id = la.user_id AND tr.date = la.maxdate
RIGHT join user on tr.user_id=user.id 
WHERE tr.status     = 'ok'
  and tr.balance_e >= ".$mincredit." 
ORDER BY tr.balance_e desc;
```